# Is there any windows command for display the path of files that were installed via pip command?

Tags: path, installation, pip, windows-10, command

I installed OpenCV program via `pip install opencv_contrib_python` in Windows 10 terminal, but the terminal only showed me the progress and where it downloaded the files from. I had a hard time to figure out where the files were installed. Is there any Windows command to display where the downloaded files will be stored? I am not asking for the path of downloaded files directly from the internet browsers, but asking for the path of downloaded files from windows command like `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip show --files opencv_contrib_python
```

Comment: Sir, you are a God. Thank you so much!